# How to position submenus to appear correctly under the main menu (CSS)?

Tags: html, css, menu, position, submenu

I've been able to create a horizontal menu using (display:inline) and I now have a drop menu thanks to sousMenu. My problem is that all the submenus, regardless of element I hovered over, appear in the same place. How do I work around this?

My menu code thus far:

```
<ul>            
 <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
 <li class="sousMenu">About Us
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Board of Directors</a></li>
   </br>
   <li><a href="#">Student Profiles</a></li>
   </br>
   <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="sousMenu">Get Involved
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Donations</a></li>
</br>
  <li><a href="#">Job Board</a></li>
</br>
  <li><a href="#">Join</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li class="sousMenu">Resources
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Connections</a></li>
  </br>
  <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  </br>
  <li><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
#navcontainer ul {
 /*margin: 0;*/
 margin-left: auto; 
 margin-right: auto;
 padding: 0;
 top:180;
 right:20;
 width:800px;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #003300;
 padding: .2em 1em;
}

#navcontainer ul li { 
 display: inline;
 padding-left:2cm; 
}

#navcontainer ul li a { 
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #030;
}

#navcontainer ul li a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #000;
}

.sousMenu:hover ul {
 display: block;
}

.sousMenu ul {
 text-align: center;
 display: none;
 list-style-type: none;
}​
```

Comment: They do not appear in the same place for me. Each one is positioned from the parent element: http://jsfiddle.net/vXhZb/

Comment: have you tried using display:inline-block; ??

Comment: @lukeocom I have tried inline-block but it still renders the same result for me.

Comment: @DrCord I'm afraid that's only on jsfiddle... I'd like for it to work outside of the jsfiddle testing program.

Comment: Then put up some code somewhere else we can see the problem on.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the parent list item to `position: relative` and the child `ul` to `position: absolute` for starters. I made some other slight modifications to your code to achieve the desired effect.

Here's the CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;
}

li {
list-style-type: none;
}
ul.main li {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.main li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}

ul.sub {
position: absolute;
display: none;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
}

ul.sub li {
display: block;
}
```

I also cleaned up the HTML a bit. You were missing a closing `</ul>` tag as well:

```
<ul class="main">            
    <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="sousMenu">About Us
        <ul class="sub about">
            <li><a href="#">Board of Directors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Student Profiles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sousMenu">Get Involved
        <ul class="sub get-involved">
            <li><a href="#">Donations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Job Board</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Join</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sousMenu">Resources
        <ul class="sub resources">
            <li><a href="#">Connections</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vXhZb/2/